# how to get spark sql group result in scala ?

Tags: apache-spark

my spark version is 2.0.2 , i use spark sql on hive , now ,i want to group by special table and save group result to redis , but i don't know how to implement it .

input table data :

```
a,1
b,1
a,2
```

expect result:

```
a , (1,2)
b , (1)
```

my code is follow：

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
object SparkSQLHiveToRedis {

 case class KP(q_id:String,kp_id:String)

 def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

val spark=SparkSession
   .builder()
    .appName("spark on sql hive to redis ")
   .enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate();

import spark.implicits._
import spark.sql
sql(" use mydb")
val ds=sql("select q_id,kp_id from ods_q_quest_kp_rel ");
ds.as[KP]

// some code need your help ......

spark.stop();

 } 
}
```

thanks for your answer !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try,

```
val ds=sql("select q_id, collect_set((kp_id) from ods_q_quest_kp_rel group by q_id");
```